# Wireshark и передача информации об устройствах

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, железо, wireshark

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Добрый вечер, уважаемые пользователи.

Возможно пост глупый, но мне очень интересно и ответа я не нашёл. 
Возможно ли, через пакет TCP передать информацию об устройствах, например таких как: ОЗУ, видеокарта, процессор и т.д.т.п.

Еще поправочка что я на Linux (запускаю программу через Wine), а сам клиент только для Windows.

Любые ссылки на литературу - я буду признателен. 
Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: программа wireshark — свободное программное обеспечение, потому отлично компилируется и запускается в любой популярной операционной системе. в т.ч. пакет с этой программой присутствует и в репозиториях всех популярных дистрибутивов операционной системы gnu/linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Возможно ли, через пакет TCP передать информацию об устройствах, например таких как: ОЗУ, видеокарта, процессор и т.д.т.п.

да, конечно. например, с помощью программы [*netcat*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat):

```
$ while :; do echo 'произвольная информация' | nc -l 12345; done
```

теперь программа будет слушать tcp-порт номер 12345 на всех интерфейсах и выдавать в ответ на подключение указанную информацию.

получить эту информацию можно с другой машины. например, с помощью той же самой программы *netcat*:

```
$ nc ip-адрес-или-имя-первой-машины 12345
произвольная информация
```

или с помощью любого web-клиента (браузера в т.ч.):

```
$ curl http://ip-адрес-или-имя-первой-машины:12345
произвольная информация
```

---

конечно, команду `echo 'произвольная информация'` можно заменить на любую другую, возвращающую в *stdout* что-то полезное. например, [*lspci*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lspci), или целый набор команд (тогда их нужно заключить в фигурные скобки, чтобы сформировать единый поток *stdout*):

```
$ while :; do { lspci; cat /proc/meminfo; cat /proc/cpuinfo; } | nc -l 12345; done
```

---

и, конечно, вы сможете увидеть содержимое принимаемых вашей машиной пакетов, например, с помощью *wireshark*.

Comment: Спасибо большое! 

Но можно ли считать id устройств и передать их? 

Команда: lspci, передаёт неполную информацию об устройствах. К тому же, клиент разве смог бы её получить? Права доступа разве у него есть?

Просите если вопросы глупые.

Comment: Я почитал мануал команды и нашёл всё необходимое. Спасибо большое еще раз!